# Check if a UITextField is characters/numbers only

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitextfield

I have this block of code....

```
let characterset = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-")
        if itemDescription.text!.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted) != nil {
            print("string contains special characters")
            let message = MDCSnackbarMessage()
            message.text = "Numbers and letters only."
            MDCSnackbarManager.show(message)
            progressView.isHidden = true
            buttonSearchOutlet.isHidden = false
        }
```

No matter what I type in, I get the snackbar to show. I expect these to be false

```
Hello
hello
hello1
hello-
```

I expect this to be true

```
Hello!
hello's
hello1@
hello$&@#
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You are checking to see whether the text is _entirely_ nonalphanumerics. As long as the text contains _any_ alphanumerics your test passes. And they all do. Perhaps you meant to _invert_ the alphanumeric character set and look for any of _those_.

Comment: @matt I tried to do from:characterSet.inverted, same result.

Comment: @soldfor Are you trying to make sure all characters are letter digits or hyphen ?

Comment: @LeoDabus thats right. I only want a-zA-Z0-9 and -. everything else isnt allowed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply check if all characters satisfy a condition and check if your string with the valid characters contais those characters.

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var isLetterDigitOrHyphen: Bool {
        allSatisfy("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-".contains)
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let str = "Hello"
if str.isLetterDigitOrHyphen {
    print("string is ok")
} else {
    print("string contains special characters")
}
```

---

```
"Hello".isLetterDigitOrHyphen  // true
"hello".isLetterDigitOrHyphen  // true
"hello1".isLetterDigitOrHyphen  // true
"hello-".isLetterDigitOrHyphen  // true

"Hello!".isLetterDigitOrHyphen  // false
"hello's".isLetterDigitOrHyphen  // false
"hello1@".isLetterDigitOrHyphen  // false
"hello$&@#".isLetterDigitOrHyphen  // false
```

---

If you would like to use regular expressions:

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var isLetterDigitOrHyphen: Bool {
        range(of:"^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,}$", options: .regularExpression) != nil
    }
}
```

---

Or using a character set:

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var isLetterDigitOrHyphen: Bool {
        unicodeScalars.allSatisfy(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-").contains)
    }
}
```

---

Of course you can simply negate the result if you would like to:

```
extension String {
    static let validCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-"
}
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var isNotLetterDigitOrHyphen: Bool {
        !unicodeScalars.allSatisfy(CharacterSet(charactersIn: .validCharacters).contains)
    }
}
```

Comment: this is greaet. and I assume if, down the road, I want to add a character they can use (for example #) I can just add that in there

Comment: @soldfor sure you can also create a static property and add your string there

Comment: Is there a good way to use a global variable? Im storing that string in Firebase to allow me to edit it if need be.

Comment: @soldfor sorry didn't see your comment. Don't use global variable. Take a look at how to implement a singleton. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/managing_a_shared_resource_using_a_singleton

Comment: Thanks. What I actually did was store it inside of firebase firecloud and grab it. This way I can add to it whenever I need.